# Kaspersky Antivirus 2013 - Database have not updated for a long time

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, kaspersky

I can't seem to fix the following situation. On a Windows 7 computer Kaspersky Anti-Virus 2013 is installed, with a working license. Every other day the user gets a popup where it says the database is out of date. She can update manually, and two days later the same problem.

[image: Kaspersky Anti-virus 2013 - Databases are out of date]

When she opens the program, she sees the following:

[image: Kaspersky - Databases have not updated for a long time]

Note the remark that "databases have not updated for a long time". A while ago I found a similar post about this saying that it was something with the proxy settings. That didn't fix it. Last week I removed the program and reinstalled, but no change. On another computer with almost similar settings it works without problems.

How can I get this working properly?

Comment: If this is in a corporate environment, check the firewall(s);  also check her scheduled tasks, whether she turns the computer off at night, how often it's set to update, etc.

Comment: This is a personal computer, turned off each day. Windows Firewall with standard settings, but I might check them. Default update settings.

Comment: Have you checked the update location (server) for the scheduled update?  Tried setting it to update every 2 hrs and see if it runs while the computer is in use?

Answer (score 0):

One important factor is to being connected to the Internet each day. For example even if you be disconnected for one day it's possible to see that message from that AV. So you need to be connected almost always, why? Because Kasper regularly (when needed) checks for update from the Internet.
After that the settings of that AV should be set correctly for downloading new signatures. So look at *Settings* -> *Update* and on the right-hand side the "Run mode" should be set on **Automatically** and the "Update source" to the **Default**.
Now everything is OK so you can update the AV manually or let it to keeps itself up-to-date automatically.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: This computer has a fast cable connection which always works. All settings are set to automatic or default.